# Passing file path string from jsp to java servlet

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

I am passing a file path from a jsp page to a Java servlet. But once the path is received by the servlet the `\` are missing.

JSP form:

```
<form action="DownloadFiles" method="POST">
    <button class="btn btn-link" type="submit" value="C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\file.txt" name="filePath">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Java Servlet Code:

```
String filePath = request.getParameter("filePath");
System.err.println(filePath);
```

`filePath` is printed out as

```
C:UsersBobDesktop\file.txt
```

Should be:

```
C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\file.txt
```

This is only happening on Windows not linux.

How can I get the correct file path in Windows?

Comment: I don't know if it is a good idea to accept the path to a file on the server from a web browser. The user could change that path to any file they want. You should have some validation at least.

Comment: There is, this is just very basic version of my code to show how the problem is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/` instead of `\`. This works for both Linux and Windows.

Or, using `\\` will do.

> \\ - Insert a backslash character(\).